# file manager using "touch (filename)"

Tags: python, file-management

How can I write a file manager using "touch (filename)" in Python?

In the code I wrote, I need to do 2 operations to create a file.
I need to create the file by typing " touch(example.txt) " instead of create on the command line.

pwd, cd (dirname), touch (filename), cat (filename), ls , rm (filename)
It is necessary to run it by entering these short commands from the console. When I wrote touch(foo.txt), must to create this file. And when "rm(foo.txt)" must to remove it.

```
if inp == "create":
    ent_filename = input("Enter new file name:> ")
    with open(ent_filename, 'w') as f:
        f.write('Create a new text file!')
```

Comment: Are you looking for [`os.system()`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-system-method/amp/) to make system calls?

Comment: Are you looking to create a console app that when run would parse text input like "touch(foo.txt)" and then create that file?

Comment: Exactly I need to make a file manager, pwd, cd (dirname), touch (filename), cat (filename), ls , rm (filename). It is necessary to run it by entering these short commands from the console. When I wrote touch(foo.txt), must to create this file. And when "rm(foo.txt)" must to remove it.

Comment: You can use `os.system()` to achieve that. For `rm(foo.txt)` my quick solution would be `os.system(''.join(command.strip(')').split('('))`. For bigger commands that would break, but for now that would do the job.

Comment: Why don't you use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)'s [`Path.touch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.touch)?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to use terminal instructions in Python, you can do this:

```py
from subprocess import call

fn = "123.txt"
cmd = f"touch {fn}" # touch
# cmd = f"rm {fn}" # rm
call(cmd, shell = True)
```

If you want to call the system api to complete these operations, you can do the following:

```py
import os

# create file and write
with open(fileName, mode) as f:
    f.write(fileContent)

# only create
with open(fileName, "w") as f:
    pass

# cat {fileName}
with open(fileName, "rb") as f:
    fileContent = f.read()
print(fileContent)

# rm {fileName}
os.remove(fileName)
```

and so on....

Comment: But "only create" will erase the data in the original file, so you may also need to optimize this code for your own project